# Invalid apk file?

Tags: android, apk

I made an application and took the .apk file from the bin folder ( eclipse project ). I installed it on my mobile which i used as an emulator earlier and it worked just fine. However when i put the file on a friends mobile it said "cant open package" or something similar when i tried to install the application.

What could be wrong since it worked on mine? The API level was 10, so nothing fuzzy about that.

I've read something about keystore but i dont understand the meaning and function of em.

Comment: try changing package name ,may be package by that name exists there but signed with a different key.

Comment: Did you allow the 3rd party application install on your friends phone? (Settings / Application / Unknown Sources)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than likely your friend phone doesn't accept unsigned packages.

You can either:
A. [Sign](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) you application
B. Enable untrusted instals on those phones via Settings > Applications > Unknown Sources

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.

Test if the size of copied APK file is same as size of file on your PC.

If they are not same, copy the APK file using a RAM reader to your PocketPC memory.